# Bootstrap-3X. Отображается некорректно меню, скрытое collapse-ом

Tags: joomla, bootstrap, php

Делаю шаблон в Joomla, Bootstrap, и возникла проблема: когда браузер уменьшается, появляется кнопка, но меню в ней себя ведет странно, вроде бы сделал его по центру, но при разных разрешениях оно то по центру, то слева, то вообще элемент меню "главная" отделяется от основного

```
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-12 TopHeader">
            <div class="visible-md visible-lg">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4 logo">
                        <?php if ($tmpl_logo) : ?>
                            <a href="/" ><img src="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/<?php echo htmlspecialchars($tmpl_logo);?>" alt="MYLOGO"/></a>
                        <?php endif;?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-8 padding-right">
                        <div class="nav navbar-nav Topmenu">
                            <jdoc:include type="modules" name="Topmenu" style="none" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

         </div>
         <div class="hidden-md hidden-lg">
            <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-4 logo">
                        <?php if ($tmpl_logo) : ?>
                            <a href="/" ><img src="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/<?php echo htmlspecialchars($tmpl_logo);?>" alt="MYLOGO"/></a>
                        <?php endif;?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-8">
                       <a class="pull-right Mobilepadding" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse"> <button class="button bt"></button></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
                      <div class="nav navbar-nav Mobilestyle">
                      <div class="center">
                        <jdoc:include type="modules" name="Topmenu" style="none" />

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

             </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 Promo">
      <jdoc:include type="modules" name="Promo" style="xhtml" />
      </div>
    </div> 
      <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 Bottom_hd"></div>
      </div>           
</div>
```

**Обновление**

Теперь понял: скрываются под кнопкой не только меню, но и лого, и даже сама кнопка попадает под это меню. Как исправить, не пойму.